# Asking open hours of the restaurant

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

This question has already been answered here:
[How to properly ask for store hours on phone?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113367/how-to-properly-ask-for-store-hours-on-phone)

However, I have one question. Can I ask the question like following?

> How long does the restaurant stay open?

Comment: I'd personally add a preposition *for* at the end..

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko You mean, How long does the restaurant stay open until?

Comment: How long do you stay open for? meaning How much time do I have to finish my meal?

Comment: Although it would certainly be understood, I would never ask *how **long** are you open?*  I would ask, *How **late** are you open?*  Or, *When do you close?*  If I knew they were closing soon I might ask, *How much **longer** will you be open?*

Comment: @EllieK ok. Is it correct to ask: *how late does the restaurant stay open?*

Comment: @ramanujan - Yes.  That would be a very common way to ask the question.

Comment: @EllieK ok. Got it.

Comment: In my experience, clarity is needed. If a restaurant 'stays open' until midnight, it may be that you have to be seated by (say) 10:30, and at 11:45, if you have not yet paid and left, the staff will be stacking the chairs, bringing you the bill, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, and understandable, but I'd probably prefer the slightly simpler "When do you close?" - You aren't really interested in the length time period when the restaurant is open; you ask that question to find out when you have to leave.  It is easier to ask the direct question.

Answer (score 1):

What are your hours?
Formal: hours of operations.
for any business.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that what you are really interested in is what time you have to arrive in order to be able to eat your meal. In that case you need to ask them both *What time do you close?* and *What time is last orders?* so you know exactly what you need to do. It is no good arriving at a restaurant which closes at 2345 at 2330 when last orders is at 2230.